# twitter4j search for users with a particular account creation date

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I want to search for all users on twitter wit a particular account creation date. So does Twitter api allows that? And if yes, how do I do so using twitter4j?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it is possible or not. However you might use following things.

For example, assume that you are searching users who has been created in 2010-03-05 (yyyy-MM-dd)

You can create a query like below by giving since and until date points like 1 day before to since point and 1 day later to until point. Because there is no explicit field to set exact date, I came up with this idea. Then, you should call SearchUsers() method with paging mechanism. You can explore how to implement pagination in this, I don't remember how it was, but you can easily find a sample on the Internet. Try the following codes, I hope it will work:

```
 try
        {
            Query query = new Query();
            query.setSince("2010-03-04");
            query.setUntil("2010-03-06");
            ResponseList<User> userList = twitterObj.searchUsers(query.toString(), -1);

            for (User userItem : userList)
            {
                // Then here you can do whatever you want by using userItem object
            }

        }
        catch (TwitterException ex)
        {
            // Do necessary error handling mechanism here
        }
```

Comment: This does not work.I guess searchUsers takes only usernames or part of usernames as parameter.

Comment: yeah, I said I am not sure about that. This result was also expected. anyway, never mind my suggestion :)

Comment: No issues bro!Thanks for this answer anyways. :)

Comment: did u get an answer to this question.?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void tweetSearch(String queryRequest) throws IOException, TwitterException{
        // Create configuration builder and set key, token etc
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
        cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("xxxxx"); 
// type your provided Consumer key and consumer secret key from twitter
//and leave access token access secret token as blank



cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("xxxx");
    cb.setOAuthAccessToken("xxxx");
    cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("xxxx");

    // Create Twitter instance
    Twitter Twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

    // Create file writer and buffer writer
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("Twitterstream.txt",true);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

    // Create Query object and set search string
    Query query = new Query("");
            //change the date as u wish...
            query.setSince("2014-06-12");
            query.setUntil("2014-06-14");
    query.setQuery(queryRequest);

    // Get query result
    QueryResult qr = Twitter.search(query);

    // Get tweets and write in the file
    while(qr.hasNext()){
        qr.nextQuery();
        List<Status> tweets = qr.getTweets();

        for (Status t: tweets){
                System.out.println(t.getId() + " - " + t.getCreatedAt() + ": " + t.getText());

            out.write("\n"+t.getId()+",");
            out.write("\t"+t.getText()+",");
            out.write("\t"+t.getUser()+",");
        }

    }
            System.out.println("Generated Twitter Stream");

}
```